# Find the similarity between two string columns of a DataFrame

Tags: python, string, pandas, nlp, similarity

I am new to programming.I have a pandas data frame in which two string columns are present.

Data frame is like below:

```
Col-1             Col-2
Update            have a account
Account           account summary
AccountDTH        Cancel
Balance           Balance Summary
Credit Card       Update credit card
```

Here i  need to check the similarity of Col-2 elements with each element of Col-1.
It Means i have to compare `have a account` with all the elements of `Col-1`.
Then find the top 3 similar one. Suppose the similarity scores are :`Account(85),AccountDTH(80),Balance(60),Update(45),Credit Card(35)`.

Expected Output is:

```
Col-2              Output
have a account     Account(85),AccountDTH(80),Balance(60)
```

Comment: How are you generating scores? This is confusing. Have you read through the help center on proper question writing?

Comment: @ Rushabh Mehta.. I don't know which similarity methods i should apply to get those scores. Kindly guide me .

Comment: I am not sure as to even what you want, so I can't really help you much.

Answer (score 13):

You can use a Python library like [`fuzzywuzzy`](https://github.com/seatgeek/fuzzywuzzy) here, which has support for this type of task:

```
from fuzzywuzzy import process

df.assign(Output=[process.extract(i, df['Col-1'], limit=3) for i in df['Col-2']])
```

Using the [`process`](https://github.com/seatgeek/fuzzywuzzy#process) method, we can get string similary scores, and then pick the top 3, if 3 exist:

The output of the above code:

```
         Col-1               Col-2                                                         Output
0       Update      have a account       [(Account, 90, 1), (AccountDTH, 64, 2), (Update, 40, 0)]
1      Account     account summary  [(Account, 90, 1), (AccountDTH, 63, 2), (Credit Card, 38, 4)]
2   AccountDTH              Cancel      [(Balance, 62, 3), (Credit Card, 43, 4), (Update, 33, 0)]
3      Balance     Balance Summary      [(Balance, 90, 3), (Credit Card, 38, 4), (Update, 30, 0)]
4  Credit Card  Update credit card   [(Update, 90, 0), (Credit Card, 90, 4), (AccountDTH, 27, 2)]
```

To speed this comparison up (natively it uses Python's sequence matcher), I would recommend installing [`python-Levenshtein`](https://github.com/ztane/python-Levenshtein)

Comment: hi, could you please tell me how I can implement the same process using python-Levenshtein? I have installed the library but idk how to implement it Sorry, I am fairly new. Thanks very much!