# i have written a python code which is not working very well with random text search

Tags: python

dataframe 1:-

colum1
 1.greasy
 2.i am tennis lover
 3.washing_machine
 4.fruit

dataframe 2:-
 colum1
 1.tennis
2.machine
3.grease
4.fruit

Output1 needed(pattern kind of match):-
 colum1           Values
========          ========
1.greasy            grease
2.i am tennis lover tennnis
3.washing_machine   machine
4.fruit              fruit

Output2 needed(exact match):-
colum1                Values
================   =============
1.greasy                 null/0
2.i am tennis lover      null/0
3.washing_machine        null/0
4.fruit                 fruit/1

***code that i tried-fuzzy_df = df1.assign(InDf2=df1.col1.isin(df2.col1).astype(int))***

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possible solution using the fuzzywuzzy ratio function to determine similarity.

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz

col1 = ["greasy", "I am tennis lover", "washing_machine", "fruit"]
col2 = ["tennis", "machine", "grease", "fruit"]

similar = [(i, j) for i in col1 for j in col2 if fuzz.ratio(i.lower(), j.lower()) >= 50]
exact_matches = {i: 0 for i in col1}  # sets initial values for each i to 0 (so far 0 matches)

# output 1
for i, j in similar:
    print(i, j)

print("=" * 25)

# output 2
for i in col1:
    for j in col2:
        if fuzz.ratio(i.lower(), j.lower()) == 100:
            exact_matches[i] += 1  # if there is a match add one to the match value for that key
    if exact_matches[i] > 0:
        print(f"{(i + ' ') * (exact_matches[i] + 1)}/{exact_matches[i]}")
    else:
        print(f"{i} null/{exact_matches[i]}")
```

Output:

```
greasy grease
I am tennis lover tennis
washing_machine machine
fruit fruit
=========================
greasy null/0
I am tennis lover null/0
washing_machine null/0
fruit fruit /1
```

Comment: after trying this code for similar i am getting error as : <class 'TypeError'>: object of type 'float' has no len()

Comment: I don't know what other code you are using with it. If you copy and paste my code into its own file, it doesn't throw any errors and it gives the output shown above.

Comment: i guess the problem was due to the reason that i was working on dataframes and you are using list as input. when i run your code on dataframe input it gives error as : object of type 'float' has no len() "   while ruuning  code line---similar = [(i, j) for i in col1 for j in col2 if fuzz.ratio(i.lower(), j.lower()) >= 50]"............... any idea how to do same thing on DFs..

Comment: I'm not super familiar with data frames yet. I'm currently learning some Pandas. There is probably some other ways to write it to fit your data frame. Basically that line does the same thing as creating a tuple of 2 items using two for loops if an item from one list is similar to an item in the other list with a fuzz ratio >= 50.

Comment: ok..then any idea how to create a list from a float object column of a dataframe?

Comment: Maybe with some research. Could you add your code of how you created those collumns to your question? Are you using Pandas? Can you add your code as well?

Comment: actually using a tool that does machine learning tasks .. so any excel sheet i upload in tool is automatically converted to pandas dataframe.. hence my input datasets are dataframes by default

Comment: Yeah I think I'm out of ideas, but I did find this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51934474/find-the-similarity-between-two-string-columns-of-a-dataframe